# How can I get Google calendar to play a sound notification for an event?

Tags: notifications, audio, google-calendar

Is it possible to get an audible notification of an event in Google Calendar?

I have a new Android smartphone which I'm trying to fathom out. I'm new to all this.

Comment: If you have a "Calendar Event..." app, the settings in there can override other settings.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at "Notifications" part of [Google Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242) page. It has full details about notification setting in all devices like Android, iOS and Computer.

1. Open the Google Calendar app.
2. In the top left, go to the main menu (touch on 3 horizontal lines).
3. Choose "Settings" at the bottom.
4. Select "General".
5. To change or turn off the sound, touch "Tone", and choose another sound or None.
6. Switch "Vibrate" to on or off.

Hope this will help you.