# Google Calendar event reminder sound is too short and I can't hear it

Tags: google-calendar

One of the main Google Calendar's functions is to remind people their events, with a scheduled sound alarm. The problem is that this sound, [I know how to change it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109447/how-can-i-get-google-calendar-to-play-a-sound-notification-for-an-event), only lasts for 1 second, so I don't hear it. Instead, when they call me, the sound lasts for very long until they hang up the phone, so I realize I'm being called. I would like if the alarm sound lasted longer, how to do it?

By the way, I have the same problem with Google Keep reminders.

I imagine some people like short sounds because they don't want to get disturbed, and they probably get reminded when they check their phones and see the notification. I want to know if it's possible to make it work like I specified, a longer loud sound like a call.

Comment: You can try solution [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/155807/131553) with modifications. Choose the apps to trigger and in action choose the sound you want. If that is not long enough , add wait xx seconds as another action followed by action for sound again

Comment: @beeshyams You are a expert, thanks, I will try that!

Comment: *LoL* I am not. Let me know once you are satisfied to post as an answer. BTW, I haven't tested your requirement, but it should work

Comment: @beeshyams Good modus operandi and idea, I answer you once I try. Also, according to the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert), and to your profile (top 0.17%) , you are a EXPERT.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "My Files" and then copy any MP3 or sounds that sound longer to be your reminder. Then go to "device storage", look for the "notifications" folder, and paste it there.

Now, go to your S-Planner and open "Settings". Now, you'll see your MP3 as the choice in the notifications tone options. Now, you can have a longer reminder tone.

Comment: Just a note that S-Planner is Samsung's specific app.

Comment: @AndrewT.  Thanks.  I was wondering WTF S-Planner is.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Xiaomi's Redmi Note 7 and even *after multiple attempts* I could not implement [Clara's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/175635/44325) since it is not allowed by MIUI.

I had to settle with having another app that rings an alarm according to my Google Calendar.

'**Event Alarm Reminder for Google Calendar**' by Lion Zöchling syncs with Google Calendar and rings an alarm that lasts longer (can be customized).

This is the only app that worked well with MIUI for me. Added bonus is that it has a decent-looking UI.

Answer (score 1):

I have both Google Calendar and Samsung Calendar installed. They seem to coexist fine, and Samsung Calendar has what you need:

Go to Settings > Calendar Settings > Alert style and set it to "Strong".  You can then customise the sound, but you have a large choice of long and loud alert sounds.

It's pretty simple but you can also see it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6Q5cAo8ezw

Answer (score 0):

I use [**Calendar Notifications**](https://f-droid.org/es/packages/com.github.quarck.calnotify/), with persistent notification and a loot of other options.